# Issue in configuring connection for report creation in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, report

here is the image describing the whole story..while connecting to dataset.Error is poping up and saying that "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" is not registered on local machine.
[image]

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

Comment: what is the database you try to connect? what have you tried?

Comment: already tried these solutions...

Comment: i am trying to connect ms access..and i have tried solution given in above link

Answer (score 0):

try adding the Reference of 'Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0.dll' to your project.

Comment: this is need to be installed..which i have already done..its refrence need not be added...